# KeyPress event equivalent in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

i have the following code in WPA, and i am trying to convert it to WPF. I tried Keydown instead of Keypress and changed, for example,

```
(e.keyChar == '-') to (e.key == e.Subtract):
```

1. its not working the same
2. I cant find the  equal sign within e.key

first code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (TextBox tb in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            tb.Enter += textBox_Enter;
        }
    }

    void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        focusedTextbox = (TextBox)sender;
    }

private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.KeyChar == '+')
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 1;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '-')
        {

            if (focusedTextbox != null)
            {
                if (focusedTextbox.Text == "")
                {
                    e.Handled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    e.Handled = true;
                    operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
                    operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
                    flag1 = 2;
                }
            }

        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '*')
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 3;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '/')
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 4;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '=')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            operand2.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand2.Imag = getOperand.Imag;

            switch (flag1)
            {
                case 1:
                    operand1 = operand1 + operand2;
                    break;
                case 2: operand1 = operand1 - operand2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    operand1 = operand1 * operand2;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (operand2.Magnitude == 0)
                    {
                        textBox1.Clear();
                        textBox2.Clear();
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot divide by a number whose magnitude is zero");
                        operand1 = new Complex();
                        operand2 = new Complex();
                        listBox1.ClearSelected();

                    }
                    else
                    operand1 = operand1 / operand2;
                    break;
            }
            string s = operand1.ToString();
            if (flag == 1)
            {
                string[] s1 = s.Split(' ');

                if (s1[1] == "-")
                {
                    textBox1.Text = s1[0];
                    textBox2.Text = "-" + s1[3];
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.Text = s1[0];
                    textBox2.Text = s1[3];
                }
            }
            else if (flag == 2)
            {
                string[] s1 = s.Split('@');
                textBox1.Text = s1[0].Trim();
                textBox2.Text = s1[1].Trim();
            }

            listBox1.Items.Add(operand1);
        }

    }
```

second code:

```
private void win_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Add)
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 1;
            e.Handled = true;

        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Subtract)
        {

            if (textBox2.Text == "")
            {
                e.Handled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
                operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
                flag1 = 2;
            }

        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Multiply)
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 3;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Divide)
        {
            operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
            flag1 = 4;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            operand2.Real = getOperand.Real;
            operand2.Imag = getOperand.Imag;

            switch (flag1)
            {
                case 1:
                    operand1 = operand1 + operand2;
                    break;
                case 2: operand1 = operand1 - operand2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    operand1 = operand1 * operand2;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    if (operand2.Magnitude == 0)
                    {
                        textBox1.Clear();
                        textBox2.Clear();
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot divide by a number whose magnitude is zero");
                        operand1 = new Complex();
                        operand2 = new Complex();
                        listBox1.UnselectAll();
                    }
                    else
                        operand1 = operand1 / operand2;
                    break;
            }
            string s = operand1.ToString();
            if (flag == 1)
            {
                string[] s1 = s.Split(' ');

                if (s1[1] == "-")
                {
                    textBox1.Text = s1[0];
                    textBox2.Text = "-" + s1[3];
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox1.Text = s1[0];
                    textBox2.Text = s1[3];
                }
            }
            else if (flag == 2)
            {
                string[] s1 = s.Split('@');
                textBox1.Text = s1[0].Trim();
                textBox2.Text = s1[1].Trim();
            }


            listBox1.Items.Add(operand1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 35):

It's very similar - but you compare e.Key to the Key enumeration.

Register your event handler somewhere (such as the constructor, or window_loaded):

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MainWindow_KeyDown);
}
```

And then in the event handler:

```
void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Subtract)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: i just discovered that nothing is working,,,, i mean .  i have 2 texchanged events and the keyDown event,, and only the first textchanged is working ,  the  other are not been executed at all..

Comment: Window_Loaded is the method which is generated for you when you double click on the WPF window in the designer. It runs when the WPF window has finished loading. It sounds like you have retyped the method instead of just registering the event handler in the one that already exists. Try making a brand new WPF application and getting my example to work in there

Comment: now im using textbox1_keyDown which have the same code ,,, i did the following
 private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
           // MessageBox.Show("msg");
            if (e.Key == Key.Add)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("msg2 ");
                operand1.Real = getOperand.Real;
                operand1.Imag = getOperand.Imag;
                flag1 = 1;
                e.Handled = true;
                  {....}
i can see the msg1 whenever i press anything ,, but if i press '+' i dont see msg2 even after closing msg1's message box.

Comment: could the problem remain  within if (e.Key == Key.Add)------  it does the same for all signs not just for +

Comment: you are using the KeyDown event of "textBox1", rather than the KeyDown event of "MainWindow". Notice how in the above example I registered the event handler to "this.KeyDown".

Comment: I found the problem... I don't have a keypad on my computer .. so key.Add is not reading the key when i press "+" or "Shift and -" .. any suggestions on how  those keys are represented within the key enumaration??

Answer (score 16):

You're looking for the [TextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.contentelement.textinput.aspx) event, or perhaps [PreviewTextInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.previewtextinput.aspx).

The EventArgs type is [TextCompositionEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.textcompositioneventargs.aspx); I believe you want the `Text` property here, but I'm not at all sure of that.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. You get any printable key in string form. Avoids doing a huge switch statement which would be region dependent.

Answer (score 7):

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="txtbx" KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler" Height="23" Width="250">
</TextBox>
```

```cs
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return)
    {
        txtbx.Text = "You Entered: " + txtbx.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice to see someone include the XML part for people who are unexperienced.