# Detect question mark independent from keyboard

Tags: c#, wpf

The goal is simple: When the user enters chars in a textbox, I want to detect if this char is the question mark key (?).
I don't care what to use (text changed, key down etc...)
One thing to mention: I am working on a german keyboard layout and therefore I need a solution independent from the keyboard (for example: `e.Key = Keys.OemQuestion` isn't working, it fires when I press the plus (+) key)

Edit: I tried **Convert.toString((char)e.Key) which returned \u0095** and **e.Key.ToString() which returned OemOpenBrackets**

Comment: `textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)`..`if (e.KeyChar == '?') {...}`?

Comment: If you want it independent from the keyboard, why are you checking `e.Key` instead of `e.KeyChar`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I am working in WPF so I have no KeyPress, but I used similar code with (char)e.Key, but I get as a result not '?' but '\u0095'

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I am working in WPF and have no e.KeyChar option (as far as i know/researched)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587270/keypress-event-equivalent-in-wpf

Comment: You are using the wrong event.  KeyDown tells you only about virtual keys, the question mark does not have a dedicated key like F1 does.  Virtual keys are the same anywhere in the world, the character they produce when pressed is not.  They depend on the active keyboard layout.  You want to be notified about characters, not keys.  In WPF use the TextInput event.  Location still matters btw, a Greek user will type ";" for a question mark, a Spanish user will write one upside-down at the start of the sentence :)

Comment: @HansPassant I tried it with the textchanged, but it is kinda messy and I was hoping for a better solution

Comment: You chose the worse solution.  A *lot* worse.  Use the correct one.

Comment: I used the textinput event (didn't know this existed...) and managed to detect the entered keys (solution as answer down below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I chose the solution from @HansPassant and managed to do it with the **TextInput** event.

First in the constructor:

```
InitializeComponent();
CommandTextBox.AddHandler(TextBox.TextInputEvent, new TextCompositionEventHandler(CommandTextBox_TextInput), true);
```

You need this code to actually fire the event

in TextInput

```
if(e.Text == "?")
{
     //Do something
}
```

NOTE:
This does not capture space, control, shift etc.