# When user types invalid characters in textbox1 and in textbox2 an "invalid character message" is appeared and the textbox1's text is made red

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I would like to make a fancy invalid character detection , like the one we see in some online websites or mobile applications. I use WPF (.NET Framework) and C# code.

Below is the XAML code of my `textbox1` (*user input*) and `textbox2` (*invalid character detector*).

> *Note that I use the Material Design themes.*

```xml
<StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,20,10,30">
    <TextBox Name="CreatedSQLDatabase"
             BorderBrush="Black" 
             materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Add New Database Name"
             Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" 
             Margin="0,0,0,0"
             FontFamily="Champagne &amp; Limousines" 
             FontSize="12"
             MaxLength="25"
             KeyDown="OnKeyDownHandler"/>
</StackPanel>
    <TextBox Name="InvalidCharacterDetection"
             materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Invalid character"
             Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingHintTextBox}" 
             Margin="10,100,10,40"
             FontFamily="Champagne &amp; Limousines" 
             FontSize="12"
             MaxLength="25"
             IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

Below is the C# code of the invalid characters event handler detector :

```cs
private void OnKeyDownHandler(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9-()/\s\p{IsGreekandCoptic}]");

    if (regex.IsMatch(e.Key.ToString()))
    {
        InvalidCharacterDetection.Text = "You Entered an invalid character";
        CreatedSQLDatabase.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
    }
    else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(CreatedSQLDatabase.Text))
    {
        InvalidCharacterDetection.Text = "Database name cannot be empty";
    }
    else if (CreatedSQLDatabase.Text.Length > 25)
    {
        InvalidCharacterDetection.Text = "Database name cannot exceed 25 characters";
    }
}
```

The output is not correct (none of the regex expressions is applied):

[image]

How could I make the `KeyEvent` handler to catch the `if` statements and make the appropriate changes in the color of the `textbox1` and the message that is appeared in the `textbox2`?

Please notify me in the comments if there is any other duplicate question regarding this one. I found the following questions So far :

- [SO question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19524105/how-to-block-or-restrict-special-characters-from-textbox)
- [SO question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587270/keypress-event-equivalent-in-wpf)

Comment: I think you should try PreviewTextInput. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38313281/some-special-characters-are-not-restricted-using-regex-in-keydown-event-in-wpf  If that doesn't work then try your regex outside this app and check that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about regular expression but I guess you want to check if it doesn't (`!`) match, don't you? Also, try `TextChanged` instead of `KeyDown` and validate the current value of `CreatedSQLDatabase.Text`:

```
private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var regex = new Regex(@"...");

    if (!regex.IsMatch(CreatedSQLDatabase.Text))
    {
        InvalidCharacterDetection.Text = "You Entered an invalid character";
        CreatedSQLDatabase.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CreatedSQLDatabase.Text))
    {
        InvalidCharacterDetection.Text = "Database name cannot be empty";
    }
    else if (CreatedSQLDatabase.Text.Length > 25)
    {
        InvalidCharacterDetection.Text = "Database name cannot exceed 25 characters";
    }
    else
    {
        CreatedSQLDatabase.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
        InvalidCharacterDetection.Text = "The database name is valid";
    }
}
```

Comment: mm8 Your answer works as requested. One slight different approach I would like regarding the correct state of the string. So for example in my example and your answer if I write Nikos@ is incorrect and the text will turn red. But if the next exact moment I write Nikos which is correct the text is still red and does not return back to black. Your answer is absolutely correct but do you know how might I can revert to the black font state if I erase the invalid character "@" and the text sais this is valid name?

Comment: I made the edit based on my comment. I figured it out :) Thanks a lot for your answer!